# Explicitly declaring assign

Tags: objective-c, assign

The Objective-C book I'm reading is using Xcode 4.2, and I think I remember reading that `strong` instead of `assign` is the new default for 4.3. Does this mean in 4.3 and up if I wanted to do an assignment for something like `@property int numerator` I'll have to write `@property (assign) int numerator` instead?

Comment: Try it! If it doesn't throw an error, then it stayed assign - you can't retain a non-object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it is always good practice to specify attributes in property declarations and not rely on defaults. Second, you can't use the strong attribute with scalar types, it is for objects.  **@property int numerator** will default to the assign attribute even in Xcode 4.4.